# Cannot invoke setViewsibility(int) on the primitive type int

Tags: activity, android, java

Как исправить ошибку?

```
R.id.textView1.setViewsibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Пишет ошибку

> Cannot invoke setViewsibility(int) on the primitive type int

Как исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
rv.setViewsibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Вы не путайте id с компонентом

Comment: Указывает на ошибку в findByName(int) - The method findByName(int) is undefined for the type MainActivity

Comment: findViewById. :-) Думал сами догадаетесь :-)

Comment: Снова ошибка - Type mismatch: cannot convert from View to TextView

Comment: Сумел исправить. Рабочий код:

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Comment: Вот это правильно!